# QWidget for ARM platform

Tags: linux, qt, arm, qt-creator, qwidget

I have a trouble with QT Creator.

I want to use Qwidget for my ARM board, but when I change the target build from "Desktop" to "ARM" the next error appears:
`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: widgets`

In my .pro file I have next info(which is related to Qwidget):

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Also everything looks fine with env variables.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: How was the Qt for your board built? It might have been configured with `-no-widgets`.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Qt was preinstalled on image for virtual machine which is provided by supplier (boards making company)

Comment: Maybe ask that supplier then. They might have assumed QtQuick UIs to be the only use case.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Yup, QtQuick is enabled there but I cannot find necessary functionality there. Also supplier allowed me to add QtWidget into the build for my board directly. Thats why I suggest that the QtWidget should works fine. But anyway, thanks for the help!